# ActionScript - Profile Speed Of Script From Code?

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, profiler

i'm trying to cave-man-profile the speed of my code from code using the date class and trace statements.  it's not working out so well.

```
package
{   
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    public function Test()
        {
        var now:Date = new Date();
        var profileSpeedMark:Number = now.getMilliseconds();

        var myArray:Array = new Array();
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            myArray.push(Math.random());

        var profileSpeedResult:Number = now.getMilliseconds() - profileSpeedMark;
        trace(profileSpeedResult);
        }
    }
}
```

the idea here is to be able to compare different ways of coding functions and determine which one is faster.  unless i'm on a super slow computer i'm not sure if this is possible, especially for really short functions.

Comment: Why not, I have measured the difference between empty cycle for 100M of iterations and cycle containing the call of empty function. I used getTimer, though.

Comment: ah, getTimer() is much more simple to use.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the way you've done things in your example code is that the `Date` class has a fixed value -- you're comparing the time before the tests with the time before the tests again.  Try instantiating another Date object after your tests and taking the time from that:

```
var before:Date = new Date();
test();
var after:Date = new Date();
var timeTaken:Number = after.time - before.time;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its convenient to use getTimer() function in the flash.utils package.

```
var t0:Number = getTimer();
computeSomeThing();
var t1:Number = getTimer();
trace("Time Elapsed: " + String(t1 - t0));
```

Comment: +1 getTimer is the most accurate method, this is how you should be doing it.